# Use SyndicationFeed to read RSS

Tags: c#, .net, rss

I like to use [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class to read RSS feed, but there remark about that for Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role not supported).

What means "Server Core Role not supported"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At this time**, .NET 4 is not supported on Windows Server 2008 Core SKUs. Perhaps in the future, support will be added.

> In Windows Server 2008 or 2008 R2, the .NET Framework version 4 is not supported in the Server Core Role.

See the [.NET Framework System Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), and more discussion on the [MSDN forums on .NET 4 Support on Windows Server Core](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetup/thread/0cb922d1-b85e-43ba-b8ac-26400491480f).

As a workaround, consider targeting your application/assembly to .NET 3.5 (or lower). Those assemblies are supported on the Windows Server 2008 Core SKUs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have found answer [Understanding Windows Server 2008 Server Core](http://www.petri.co.il/understanding-windows-server-2008-core.htm)

> A Server Core installation provides a
>   minimal environment for running
>   specific server roles, which reduces
>   the maintenance and management
>   requirements and the attack surface
>   for those server roles. A server
>   running a Server Core installation
>   supports the following server roles:
>
> - Active Directory Domain Services (AD    DS)
> - Active Directory Certificate Services    (AD CS)
> - Active Directory Lightweight    Directory Services (AD LDS)
> - DHCP Server
> - DNS Server
> - File Services
> - Print Services
> - Streaming Media Services
> - Internet Information Services (IIS)
> - Hyper-V